# Images not being cached

Tags: xcode, swift, caching

I am loading data this way:

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);

if IJReachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
 request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: Double.infinity);
}

subtitleLabel.loadRequest(request);
```

And it works perfectly for me including the caching. The only problem is it won't cache the images from the page and it loads pretty slowly.. Is there a way to cache them?

(I know I am still using the old XCODE but I can't update yet)

Returned HTML Headers:

```
Array
(
    [Host] => ***.nl
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Cache-Control] => max-age=0
    [Accept] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [Upgrade-Insecure-Requests] => 1
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8,hr;q=0.6,nl;q=0.4
    [Cookie] => PHPSESSID=dnvrv65pbvmrbfhi9kfskjb715
    [GEOIP_ADDR] => 84.25.56.128
    [GEOIP_CONTINENT_CODE] => EU
    [GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE] => NL
    [GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME] => Netherlands
    [Content-Length] => 0
)
```

Comment: Check the headers of the response for the image request using a tool like Charles or Red Bot. It's possible the server is telling the client not to cache it.

Comment: Well the server I am getting the data from is also mine. It's an html page populated with PHP.

Comment: in case .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad all is ok, right? In case of .UseProtocolCachePolicy your server needs to be setup right about cache policy.

Comment: No in case of ReturnCacheDataElseLoad it doesn't return an image at all actually..

Comment: Please update your question with the HTTP headers returned from the server when the request is made from the client.

Comment: I just updated my question with the Headers

Comment: I also noticed that some images do get cached while some don't. But I can't find the differences since they are all from the same page. Could this be a memory issue? It's like 2 images that are saved in cache. All the others arn't.

Comment: The header Cache-Control: max-age=0 implies that the content is considered stale (and must be re-fetched) immediately, which is in effect the same thing as Cache-Control: no-cache.